# How to convert document snapshot into a Stream data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
DocumentSnapshot doc = await userRef.document(widget.currentuserId).get();
user = User.fromDocument(doc);
bioController.text = user.bio;
usernameController.text = user.username;
displayNameController.text = user.displayName;
```

How to convert this in Stream data?

I tried this but there is some error I can't figure it out:

```
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> doc = await userRef.document(widget.currentuserId).snapshots();
user = User.fromDocument(doc);
bioController.text = user.bio;
usernameController.text = user.username;
displayNameController.text = user.displayName;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `get()`, you get `Future<DocumentSnapshot>`, you need to use `snapshots`.

```
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> stream = userRef.document(widget.currentuserId).snapshots();
stream.listen((snapshot) {
  // snapshot is DocumentSnapshot
});
```

Comment: Stream<DocumentSnapshot> stream =
        userRef.document(widget.currentuserId).snapshots();
    stream.listen((snapshot) {
      // snapshot is DocumentSnapshot
      user = User.fromDocument(snapshot);
      bioController.text = user.bio;
      usernameController.text = user.username;
      displayNameController.text = user.displayName;
    });

Comment: I used your code like this but it gives me error bio was called on null

Comment: If you can post a minimal reproducible code, I can assist you better.